# React set-state doesn't update in fetch success function (on key up event)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, setstate

I have a search `component` containing an input on which I defined a `key up event handler function` for fetching data based on entered string. As you can see below:

```
class SearchBox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            timeout: 0,
            query: "",
            response: "",
            error: ""
        }
        this.doneTypingSearch = this.doneTypingSearch.bind(this);
    }
    doneTypingSearch(evt){
        var query = evt.target.value; 
        if(this.state.timeout) clearTimeout(this.state.timeout);
        this.state.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1/?name=query' , {
                method: "GET"
            })
            .then( response => response.json() )
            .then(function(json) {
                console.log(json,"successss") 
                //Object { userId: 1, id: 1, title: "delectus aut autem", completed: false }  successss

                this.setState({
                    query: query,
                    response: json
                })
                console.log(this.state.query , "statesssAfter" )
            }.bind(this))
            .catch(function(error){
                this.setState({
                    error: error
                })
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" onKeyUp={evt => this.doneTypingSearch(evt)} />        
            <InstantSearchResult data={this.state.response} /> 
        </div>
        );
    }
}
export default SearchBox;
```

The problem is the `setState` which I used in the second `.then()`. The response won't update . I want to update it and pass it to the `InstantSearchResult` component which is imported here. Do you have any idea where the problem is ?

**Edit - Add InstantSearchResult component**

```
class InstantSearchBox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            magicData: ""
        }
    }
    // Both methods tried but got error =>  Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
    componentDidUpdate(props) {
        this.setState({
            magicData: this.props.data
        })
    }
    shouldComponentUpdate(props) {
        this.setState({
            magicData: this.props.data
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>{ this.state.magicData}</h1>
        );
    }
}
export default InstantSearchBox;
```

Comment: You cannot directly `console.log(this.state)` directly after `this.setState`. [See the third paragraph](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: What returns in `response`? Is there a status code? Also is `query` on the end of your url supposed to be the value of the `query` variable?

Comment: query is a string the user is typed . the fetch is successfully returns some value. but the state doesn't update.Do you think the problem is with the response which I receive ? @MaxBaldwin

Comment: @FrankerZ You mean the state is already updated ? But not accessible in console.log ?

Comment: To piggy back off @FrankerZ, try console logging state in `render` rather than right after it is set.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin `this.setState()` has a callback (Second parameter), that you can hook into right after the state gets updated.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin You're right it's ok in render section but do you know why the data is not passing through  InstantSearchResult  component ? How can I access that in this component ? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @MaxBaldwin take a look at this . this is what I'm going to do => https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/component_will_receive_props.html

Comment: Can we see `InstantSearchResult`? Do you call `this.props.data` in a place where the data would be updated?

Comment: @MaxBaldwin Checkout my Question Edit section please .

Comment: @MaxBaldwin Thanks a lot I've find out that I just simply should use this.props to access the updated props in my second component.

Comment: @Afsane.F, so it works now?

Comment: @MaxBaldwin Yes . Thanks for your consideration and help :pray:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

Be aware that `setState` is `asynchronous` reading [**this article**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwji29mjtrrfAhVFhqQKHW98AzIQFjAAegQIChAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2F%40wereHamster%2Fbeware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3&usg=AOvVaw17lMmro2tlNxCGHeuMZ5cX).

I've understand that the `setState` works fine in my `fetch success` the problem was the `console.log` which I shouldn't use it after `setState` instead I `console.log` in `render()` and I found out that the `state` updates correctly .

The other thing I wasn't careful for was the `InstantSearchResult Constructor`! When I `re-render` the `SearchBox` component consequently the `InstantSearchResult` renders each time but it's `constructor` runs just once. And if I use `setState` in `InstantSearchResult` I will face an `infinite loop` so I have to use `this.props` instead to pass the data to the second component.

Answer (score 2):

`this` has been overridden inside the promise callback function. You to save it to a variable:

```
doneTypingSearch(evt){
        var _this = this,
            query = evt.target.value; 
        if(this.state.timeout) clearTimeout(this.state.timeout);
        this.state.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1/?name=query' , {
                method: "GET"
            })
            .then( response => response.json() )
            .then(function(json) {
                console.log(json,"successss") 
                //Object { userId: 1, id: 1, title: "delectus aut autem", completed: false }  successss

                _this.setState({
                    query: query,
                    response: json
                })
                console.log(_this.state.query , "statesssAfter" )
            }/*.bind(this)*/)
            .catch(function(error){
                _this.setState({
                    error: error
                })
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: nope it didn't work out! I think maybe the problem is that when I try to pass the updated response to another component like this =><InstantSearchResult data={this.state.response} />  I can not access the response in this component . Is this right ?

Comment: Generally is this a acceptable way to pass the data to another component ?

Comment: @Afsane.F This answer is also probably a part of the issue.

Comment: It's actually preferred, that you simply continue using arrow functions to prevent `this` from being overwritten. `.then((json) => {...`. Avoid those pesky `this` overwrites.

Comment: It's not about "this" .

Comment: Why this line is in the constructor `this.doneTypingSearch = this.doneTypingSearch.bind(this);` ?